# Pyramid localization: not created .pot file

Tags: python, localization, pyramid, mako

I need to localize my pyramid application, but I have an issue.
The `setup.py` file contains the following `message_extractors` variable:

```
message_extractors = { '.': [
      ('templates/**.html', 'mako', None),
      ('templates/**.mako', 'mako', None),
      ('static/**', 'ignore', None)
]},
```

I've created directory `my_package_name/locale`. In `__init__.py` I added `config.add_translation_dirs('my_package_name:locale')`.

But, when I run
`(my_virtual_env): python setup.py extract_messages`

I receive messages

```
running extract_messages
error: no output file specified`
```

If I understand correctly, `extract_messages` does not require the --output-file parameter in this case.

What is the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also need setup.cfg in the same directory as setup.py, containing roughly this:

```
[compile_catalog]
directory = YOURPROJECT/locale
domain = YOURPROJECT
statistics = true

[extract_messages]
add_comments = TRANSLATORS:
output_file = YOURPROJECT/locale/YOURPROJECT.pot
width = 80

[init_catalog]
domain = YOURPROJECT
input_file = YOURPROJECT/locale/YOURPROJECT.pot
output_dir = YOURPROJECT/locale

[update_catalog]
domain = YOURPROJECT
input_file = YOURPROJECT/locale/YOURPROJECT.pot
output_dir = YOURPROJECT/locale
previous = true
```

Of course, you will replace YOURPROJECT with your project name. I think the setup.cfg file used to be a part of the projects before pyramid 1.5 but now that pyramid uses lingua and gettext instead of babel it is not needed anymore. You might be better off if you follow current pyramid docs:
http://pyramid.readthedocs.org/en/latest/narr/i18n.html